# Android App Keeps Getting Denied for Android Ad ID Policy

Tags: java, android, admob, google-advertising-id

I keep getting my app rejected from the Google Play Store.

> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section
>   4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

I tried StartApp instead of AdMob for a week, and then I got the notification that it is being taken down. I have since reverted to an older version before I used StartApp. I do not request any permissions in XML or anything special in app gradle. Possibly this might be occurring since the SDK's are in the package?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.starenkysoftware.benshapiro"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 25
        versionName "2.05"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.starenkysoftware.benshapiro">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-6127266629309110~9895064255"/>
        <activity android:name="com.starenkysoftware.benshapiro.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BenButton" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please let me know if there are any suspicious plugins to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass this validation your app must provide a privacy policy from within the app itself and the policy must also be hosted on an active link which needs to be placed in the designated field within the Google Play Console. You can read more about how to solve your issue [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-fix-advertising-id-policy-violation-in-google-play-store-6d9cf92d335d). Hopefully this solves your issue.